# How to get HTML row element while also conditionally search for another value in row

Tags: javascript, html-parsing

I have a script to get data from a site but want more control over it. I have never really used Javascript before; I found the script and am working to make it better in Google Scripts. Right now I go into the row tag and grab the value I need but, I can only grab the first row. There is a date value in the row also. I want to have this included when trying to pull in the data. Is there a way I can check additional items in the row? Right now I have the below.

```
    var url = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?CIK="+company+"&type="+filetype+"&owner=exclude&action=getcompany&Find=Search";
     var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
     var regEx = new RegExp("\<a href=.(\/cgi-bin.+type=v)");
```

the above is what I have now. The regEx is getting the link I need; this is the item I would like more control over. I was thinking to pull out all rows and as text and match the date, or better yet have a condition to filter for where date is < or > a date provided as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You may parse fetched results to html and then query all the additional data you need:

```
fetch(url).then(res => {
    return res.text();
}).then(text => {
    // Parse text into the DOM object
    let parser = new DOMParser(); // <= native browser API
    let doc = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
    // Select some data from the DOM
    doc.querySelector('{some selector for the data you are looking for}');
}).catch(err => {
    console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
});
```

Comment: That looks to make sense. I am getting an error on the line with then(text); not sure why so far though.

Comment: Syntax error, my bad. Fixed it `.. }).then(text => {...`